# Are Google Chrome Base64 methods capable of handling binary data from the File API?

Tags: html, google-chrome, base64, fileapi

I am using btoa and atob for Base64 but the atob method doesn't work on binary data! Just text. How can I solve this?

```
if(!!window.createBlobURL || !!window.createObjectURL) {
    var bb = new BlobBuilder();
    var reader = new FileReader();
    var url_creator = window.createBlobURL || window.createObjectURL;
    bb.append(atob(msg.bit.file.data));
    reader.onloadend = function(e) {
      bb = new BlobBuilder();
      bb.append(e.target.result);
      var url = url_creator(bb.getBlob(msg.bit.file.type));
      window.open(url);
    }
    reader.readAsBinaryString(bb.getBlob(msg.bit.file.type));
  }
```

Where msg.bit.file.data is the base64 encoded file.

Comment: Can you show how you load the binary data? Is the binary data originally in base64? Even if you manage to decode it, how are you going to display it?

Comment: Yes, please post some code which shows exactly what you're trying to do.  Without that, this is pretty difficult to answer.

Answer (score 1):

If your data is binary already (TypedArray) append on the BlobBuilder should just work.

If the data is returned from XMLHttpRequest in Chrome at least you have access to responseBlob property, which can be used directly in BlobBuilder.append()

Comment: Setting `xhr.responseType ='blob'` is not implemented in Chrome yet. Star [crbug.com/52486](http://crbug.com/52486).